# WebRTC Multi Connection doesn't fire onstream() Event, a=sendrecv

Tags: ionic-framework, server, socket.io, webrtc, sdp

I'm developing an Ionic 3 App with a video Chat.
So far, the main code seems to work very well (between 2 browser tabs).
When joining a room with my Android Phone, the remote stream's `onstream()` event doesn't get fired.
That means, that the phones videos doesn't get appended. But the connection is established and I can send e.g. text data.

Are there maybe any specifique required ports to open?
So far, the phone has a connection to webrtcweb.com:7788 turn server (opened in browser) and our private signaling server. Sadly I don't know how to test the connection to stun.l.google.com:19302.

I'm thankful for any advises.

**EDIT:**

When joining with Android App, the Desktop user gets following output:

```
Remote peer's sdp: v=0
o=- 7170415342919352598 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE audio video data
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=audio 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 111 103 104 9 0 8 110 112 113 126
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:yGlN
a=ice-pwd:zcWTohvOYAJLPcqU/XXcHchf
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7E:2C:7F:E2:13:22:2A:43:50:B6:D6:B5:2E:E2:95:6D:77:78:59:44:47:19:51:DB:DE:03:DD:A9:12:9C:A3:BF
a=setup:active
a=mid:audio
a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:111 opus/48000/2
a=rtcp-fb:111 transport-cc
a=fmtp:111 minptime=10;useinbandfec=1
a=rtpmap:103 ISAC/16000
a=rtpmap:104 ISAC/32000
a=rtpmap:9 G722/8000
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:110 telephone-event/48000
a=rtpmap:112 telephone-event/32000
a=rtpmap:113 telephone-event/16000
a=rtpmap:126 telephone-event/8000
m=video 9 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 98 96 97 99 100 101 108 109 124
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:yGlN
a=ice-pwd:zcWTohvOYAJLPcqU/XXcHchf
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7E:2C:7F:E2:13:22:2A:43:50:B6:D6:B5:2E:E2:95:6D:77:78:59:44:47:19:51:DB:DE:03:DD:A9:12:9C:A3:BF
a=setup:active
a=mid:video
a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:3 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=extmap:4 urn:3gpp:video-orientation
a=extmap:5 http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
a=extmap:7 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
a=recvonly
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtcp-rsize
a=rtpmap:98 VP9/90000
a=rtcp-fb:98 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:98 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:98 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack
a=rtcp-fb:98 nack pli
a=rtpmap:96 VP8/90000
a=rtcp-fb:96 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:96 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:96 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack
a=rtcp-fb:96 nack pli
a=rtpmap:97 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:97 apt=96
a=rtpmap:99 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:99 apt=98
a=rtpmap:100 H264/90000
a=rtcp-fb:100 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:100 transport-cc
a=rtcp-fb:100 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack
a=rtcp-fb:100 nack pli
a=fmtp:100 level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=42001f
a=rtpmap:101 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:101 apt=100
a=rtpmap:108 red/90000
a=rtpmap:109 rtx/90000
a=fmtp:109 apt=108
a=rtpmap:124 ulpfec/90000
m=application 9 DTLS/SCTP 5000
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:30
a=ice-ufrag:yGlN
a=ice-pwd:zcWTohvOYAJLPcqU/XXcHchf
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 7E:2C:7F:E2:13:22:2A:43:50:B6:D6:B5:2E:E2:95:6D:77:78:59:44:47:19:51:DB:DE:03:DD:A9:12:9C:A3:BF
a=setup:active
a=mid:data
a=sctpmap:5000 webrtc-datachannel 1024
```

> a=mid:audio 
>   a=extmap:1 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:ssrc-audio-level 
>   a=recvonly
>
> a=mid:video a=extmap:2 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset a=extmap:3
>   http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time a=extmap:4
>   urn:3gpp:video-orientation a=extmap:5
>   http://www.ietf.org/id/draft-holmer-rmcat-transport-wide-cc-extensions-01
>   a=extmap:6 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/playout-delay
>   a=extmap:7
>   http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-content-type
>   a=extmap:8 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/video-timing
>   a=recvonly

These lines seem interesting to me. It seems as if the **Android App is receiving** only, but it set this:

```
this.connection.sdpConstraints.mandatory = {
      OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
      OfferToReceiveVideo: true
    };
```

When running two browser tabs, the output says correctly `a=sendrecv`

EDIT2:

I just tried using the public Test Signlaing Server: https://rtcmulticonnection.herokuapp.com:443/

And oh wow, it's working from Android to Desktop!

That means, that my private is configured wrong or behind some unknown ports.
To set it up, I used this tutorial:

https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/socketio-over-nodejs

Any suggestions? Thanks